# Local CSV file load to snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to scheulde a task to load csv file to internal stage daily without using any scheduler...source is local file path and target is snowflake table

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *schedule a task without any scheduler*? To load something on a schedule basis (daily) you most probably need a scheduler. So to load a file from local path you can use a combination of [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) with a cron job to do a PUT of that file to a stage in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored Snowpipe with auto_ingest?

You set up a notification service, on AWS this is a combination of SQS and SNS that calls Snowpipe to ingest new files.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html

There would be something similar for Azure